# Collinear points in a beautiful circle geometry problem

Tags: geometry

[image]

Prove that $\angle BPC=\alpha$, $\angle OMN=\alpha$.
Prove that $XYAM$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.
Prove that $\angle XYM=\angle BCP$.
Prove that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are collinear.

The first three proofs are pretty straight forward, but I can't see the answer to the last one? Apparently, $\angle ZYM=180^\circ-\angle XYM$, but I can't see how to proceed? Furthermore, it doesn't seem like $COYZ$ is a cyclic quadrilateral..

Answer (score 0):

$\angle ZCY = \angle BPA = \angle MPN = \angle MON = \angle ZOY$ implies $COYZ$ is cyclic.

[image]

Then, $red + purple = yellow + purple = yellow + brown = 180^0$. Hence X, Y, Z are collinear.